# coded ui testing with visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, dynamics-crm-2011

We are looking for a TEST SOLUTION for Microsoft CRM in which we can automate UI tests.  I was looking at Visual Studio 2012 "Coded UI testing", and it appears that you need to have the whole project source code to be able to code the tests.  So my question is: "Can Visual Studio (or TFC) coded UI testing be used for EXTERNAL applications that you don't have the source code for"?

Answer (score 2):

Coded UI does not need or use the source code of the application. Coded UI works entirely at the user interface of the application. It uses the same mechanisms as screen readers, as used by sight-impaired people, for observing items on the screen. Similarly, it uses the input mechanisms that alternative keyboards and pointers would use. These are the MSAA and UIA interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

Basically I could not answer your direct question (I don't know VS Coded UI Tests). As Adrian already mentioned a UI test does not require that you have access to the sources because you are testing against a running application.

However, as Dynamics CRM 2011 is mainly a web application you could use a library like [ieunit](https://code.google.com/p/ieunit/) for executing your tests with IE.

Since Rollup 12 Dynamics CRM 2011 also supports other browsers so you could also use frameworks like [zombie.js](http://zombie.labnotes.org/) or [phantom.js](http://phantomjs.org/)

Answer (score 0):

There's no requirement for access to the source code but all UI automation frameworks including Coded UI work by manipulating the DOM of the rendered page.  I think you're getting confused with server-side source and the rendered HTML source.

Past experience has led me to the conclusion that whilst automated UI testing is something that can be achieved with CRM 2011, the maintenance of the generated scripts is generally not worth it.  The number of popups / iframes used in CRM 2011 make the scripts very brittle.

Answer (score 0):

Per this page - Supported Configurations and Platforms for Coded UI Tests and Action Recordings http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380742.aspx, the Dynamics CRM web client is fully supported for VS CUIT action recordings.